# React Native - Native Base Picker shows label instead of Value

Tags: react-native, native-base

Native base picker renders label instead of value

```
<Picker.Item label="Ten" value="10 />
```

It renders Ten after selection, is it possible to make it render 10?

React Native Version: 0.58.6

Native Base Version: 2.12.0

Comment: That's how Picker works

Answer (score 1):

That's how it is supose to work, if you want `10` to appear you have to set the label to `10`

```
<Picker.Item label="10" value="10 />
```